# How to use Homebrew to install terminal based Lynx browser instead of Cask (GUI)

Tags: terminal, homebrew

I am trying to get Lynx for use in the terminal up and running under OS X (Mojave). Using the commands under only installs Cask GUI (which appearst to require a licence regardless). Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
Computer:~ username$ brew install lynx
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a formula and a cask named lynx. To install the formula just run:

```
$ brew install lynx
Warning: Treating lynx as a formula. For the cask, use homebrew/cask/lynx
==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/lynx-2.8.9rel.1_1.catalina.bottle.tar.gz
==> Downloading from https://d29vzk4ow07wi7.cloudfront.net/b7b36f0697736fc1744026c18968bec4d5c1433356678e853d734406f9dc3612?response-content-disposition=attac
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Pouring lynx-2.8.9rel.1_1.catalina.bottle.tar.gz
  /usr/local/Cellar/lynx/2.8.9rel.1_1: 11 files, 2.2MB
```

Then:

```
$ lynx apple.stackexchange.com
```

shows:

[image]